# apis with http domain is not working in xcode 7.1

Tags: http, ios9, xcode7.1, app-transport-security

Hi I upgraded my xcode to 7.1.1. All apis with http:XXXX.com working fine until upgradation. But now it is not working. I added App Transport Security Settings with Allow Arbitrary Loads to true in plist also. Then also apis are not working. I am getting 500 internal server error. Please help me to fix this.

Answer (score 0):

a look at this link:
http://iosdevtips.co/post/121756573323/ios-9-xcode-7-http-connect-server-error

add this code in file Info.plist

```
<key>NSAppTransportSecurity</key>
<dict>
    <key>NSAllowsArbitraryLoads</key>
    <true/>
</dict>
```

hope it works for you, for me it worked, hug